# Common parts in virtual environments

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

The are quite a few packages which I use from every single virtual environment (e.g., `pylint` and `jupyter`). Do I really have to install them in every single environment? (If I don't, `jupyter` does not find the packages).

I thought that I should be able to install the common packages as `pip install --user ...` but then there seems to be no "official" way to revert to the state prior to the first `workon` call (except for starting a new shell or `unset VIRTUAL_ENV` - *right*?), so, apparently, if I use virtual environments for *a* project, I have to use them *always*.

So, is there an official way to share packages between all virtual environments?

Comment: You could `--use-site-packages`, though I'm pretty sure that does exactly the opposite of what you want to do :P

Comment: Yes. For such a case, I include a requirements file in the code. It greatly simplifies what you have to do to set up a new env. It will not help if your problem is speeding up a test environment that you commonly create and destroy. For that, you may want to consider hosting a copy of each package, so pip can just copy them from some other local location.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: what does your "yes" refer to?

Comment: Sorry, I went with the first question mark. I don't know of any way to share some packages, but not others, between different virtualenvs (other than to install them).

Comment: @KennyOstrom: thanks.